# Passing parameter to a GET request to retrieve specific information

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to retrieve (GET) specific information based on a parameter that is passed. My code looks like this:

In `index.js`:

```
export var comments = (userId) => { 
    return new Promise((value) => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:1000/getreviews/:userId')
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data.comment);
        })
    })
}
```

In `routes.js`:

```
router.route('/:userId').get((req, res) => {
    Users.find({user: req.params.userId}) 
        .then((reviews) => res.json(reviews)
    );
});
```

So I want to get relevant information. To give a higher-level idea of what is going on--there are multiple modals, and when a specific one is clicked I want to get specific information from the database, instead of getting all the information from the database and then do the extraction of relevant information in `index.js` based on the user's id. That way, I will be getting all the information on every modal click which is not efficient so I want to avoid it.

Comment: Please remove the Java tag since it’s not related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing the GET request in a different way solved the issue:

```
axios({ 
            method: 'get',
            url: 'http://localhost:1000/getreviews/',
            params: {
                user: userId 
            })
```

Then I could access the `userId` in `routes.js` through `req.query.user` and it will give me the `userId` I just passed.

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem exactly, is `Users.find({user: req.params.id})` not returning the expected value? mongoose has `findById` which queries the db looking for the object with that specific id, in your case :

```
Users.findById(req.params.userId) 
        .then((reviews) => res.json(reviews)
    );
```

edit: it seems like you're passing `undefined` as a parameter `find`, note that the name of the variable that is stored in params must be the same as the parameter you provided in your get method which is `userId`, so use `req.params.userId` instead.

edit2: js part

```
export var comments = (userId) => { 
    return axios.get(`http://localhost:1000/getreviews/${userId}`)
        .then((response) => {
            return response.data
        })

}
```

Comment: I get `failed to load resource... 500` in `routes.js`. It does not look like I am passing properly `userId` which the `comments` function gets

Comment: Definitely was a problem, but it still doesn't work. And to check my concern in the first comment, I console logged `req.params.userId` and nothing was shown in the console... (I did it just before the `find`)

Comment: if you're using the first code to get the comments, i don't see any id being passed, you have to put the value of the id in your like, `\`http://localhost:1000/getreviews/${valueId}\`` or `value` instead` of `valueId` depending on how you're calling that Premise

Comment: I tried these examples, but the parameter is still shown as it is not being used.

Comment: well you have to post your whole code, otherwise we can't really tell what you're doing wrong, keep in mind that the whole purpose of using `axios` is to do high level requests, which means `axios.get(link).then()...` instead of manipulating the requests your self, usually people use `fetch` for that

Comment: I was able to achieve what I want with the code I've included in the answer. There is a way to use the short notation with Axios to achieve it, but it is less clear.